# Filter on relation property

Tags: mongoose, strapi

I have a content with a simple relation (using MongoDB, btw):

```
Professional:
  - name
  - categories (has many)
```

```
Categories:
  - name
  - slug
```

A professional can have up to many categories as he wants.

I want to filter professionals that have certain categories, like:

`Professionals that have category 'foo'`

So far I've tried this:

```
/professionals?categories.slug=foo
/professionals?categories.name=foo
/professionals?categories._id=(a id)
```

None of these returns the proper values. Is there any way to do this manually through mongoose?

Comment: Can you add Professional and Categories model codes and sample documents as json  and the expected output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tested with the last version of Strapi and it works well.

Your 3 requests worked.

Here is a screen record of what I did - https://www.loom.com/share/e762efba49bc41f290ecf75fa983159e

Let me know if I messed something.

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for your time! My relation is set-up differently (http://i.imgur.com/nGDBHuU.png). Is it possible this way or I've messed up? As for now I have set my relation like yours and it's been working fine but it creates and additional field at `ProfessionalCategories`, which seems unnecessary for my case.

Comment: Just tried again with your relation type and the last version of Strapi (beta.18.4) -https://www.loom.com/share/f08a62677e604df8939af1b187d5090f

Comment: I have the same problem as in the original post except I use SQLite. I can't get the query to work. Additionally I noticed that when I pass the `categories=X` param, instead of getting objects whose category list includes X, I get the object with id X.

Comment: Please add your code example to the answer instead of linking to a screen recording (which is now 404)

Comment: @JimLAURIE Links are 404 please update answer